# Align windows with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, vmware, window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a shortcut to tile windows to left or right side of the screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122674/is-there-a-shortcut-to-tile-windows-to-left-or-right-side-of-the-screen)

I'm running 12.04 inside VMWare Workstation.

Windows 7 provides a very useful feature: use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to align the current window on the left/right half of the screen (useful for terminal windows on wide-screen, etc).

Is there an equivalent available for Ubuntu?

So far I was able to emulate <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> (maximize window), but can't find anything for left/right alignments.

Just to be clear: I am not talking about "Move to Workspace" or so, I'm talking about resizing the current window on the current screen/workspace to only take the left/right half of the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/41566/how-do-i-get-aero-snap-in-unity-2d/105735#105735 or possibly this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/122674/is-there-a-shortcut-to-tile-windows-to-left-or-right-side-of-the-screen/123222#123222

Comment: @fossfreedom: yes, I'd say so

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The same **snap** feature exists in Ubuntu 12.04, only in Ubuntu you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>FLAG</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>. This only works for Unity 3D though. In Unity 2D you'll still have UP and DOWN, but not LEFT and RIGHT.

---

With `FLAG` I mean the flag/Windows/system/super/... key.

Comment: thanks, sorry, never heard `FLAG` in that context and was confused. Seems it doesn't work for me, tried both Ubuntu and Ubuntu 2D. Maybe the cause is because I'm running inside VMWare?

Comment: @mark It'd be very likely that that is the problem. I think the Windows/Super/Flah/System/... key doesn't get sent to the virtual machine. You can set a different shortcut key with `CompizConfig Settings Manager`, which you can find in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: thanks, I took a look. I'm pretty sure sending the Windows-Key inside VMWare works, because I can and have a shortcut `Windows-Key+Up` to maximize a window -> works. I guess even choosing "Ubuntu" on the login screen is really "Ubuntu 2D" inside VMWare, aka no real 3D acceleration ...

Comment: @mark Yeah, you're probably running Unity 2D then. Snapping windows to the left or right side of the screen only works in Unity 3D. No way I know of to get it working in Unity 2D.