# Setting keyboard shortcuts within Ubuntu 12.04 (Compose Shortcut not available)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I use Ubuntu Studio 12.04 as a Fusion VM under Mac OSX Mavericks.  I have been trying to define a shortcut key to snap a window to the left half or right half of the screen.  I can do this with a cursor move and would like to do it with keystrokes.

I open up Settings Manager --> Window Manager --> Keyboard and I can see the Actions and Shortcuts columns

I doubleclick on an Action and a popup opens but the Compose Shortcut tool mentioned in the Help file does not appear.  Therefore I cannot change or reassign any of these.

Steps I have taken:

I have looked at
[Align windows with keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132348/align-windows-with-keyboard-shortcuts)
and the other links suggested in it along with several other searches
Per above, I can get to the settings window but can't change the setting

I have tried Compiz several times and have not been able to get it to work stably. Too many of its features conflict with one another or my underlying system.  This

I have logged in using ubuntustudio and Xfce options at the login prompt.  There is no difference in settings menu behavior