# Unable to resize windows

Tags: 12.04, gnome, resize

One of my ubuntu machines, a netbook running Gnome classic on Ubuntu 12.04 (32bit), has a problem: I cannot resize windows. I can unmaximize them and remaximize them, and the resize icons do appear when I place the mouse pointer on the edges, but I cannot grab and resize those edges.

I have googled around and found people with problems like borders being too thin and hard to grab -- this is not the case here. It is also not application specific -- I cannot resize any windows.

What should I look at and fix? I am a developer and can get around a terminal without destroying things fine. I just don't know where to start.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're using Gnome-classic with Compiz, and in that case resizing windows doesn't work because the plugin is disabled by default (not sure why).

To enable it, install CCSM:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then run CCSM:

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>ccsm+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Then in CCSM enable the resize plugin:
[image]

If resize doesn't work immediately, you may need to restart Compiz:

```
compiz --replace & disown
```

Comment: Starting compizconfig-settings-manager did not work for me, but it worked running it trough the menus.

After that your solution worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in 14.04.3, using Unity. Window resize just stopped working in the middle of my workday.

I already had CCSM installed. When I opened CCSSM, "Resize Windows" was already checked.

**FIX:** By simply unchecking (wait a few seconds, screen flickers a bit), then re-checking "Resize Windows" (wait a few seconds), the issue was fixed for me. No need to reboot or restart anything else.