# Ubuntu 12.10, cannot resize any window

Tags: unity, 12.10, window, resize

I am using the unity interface and i usally work with maximized windows.
However lately i noticed that i cannot resize windows.
I can get them maximized and to normal state.

When in normal state i move the mouse to the border and the cursor changes to the "resize cursor" but then nothing happens when trying to drag the border.

Starting a guest session i can see that resizing works so it has something to do with my profile.

Lately i used gsettings to disable overlay scrollbars but even resetting to default values does not solve the problem and i am not pretty sure the problem started after using gsettings.

Any solution that does not require resetting everyting?

As an extreme measure what files should i delete to reset the profile settings?

Thanks

Comment: This is simple, please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/219411/unable-to-resize-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first let's reset compiz and gsettings to default. Press Ctrl-Alt-t. In the terminal run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amith/ubuntutools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-reset
```

finally

```
unity-reset
```

For tweaking ubuntu install: ... ubuntu-tweak

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

In the dash search for "ubuntu tweak"

Once open, click Tweaks tab, then Miscellaneous, then toggle Overlay scrollbars off

[image]

Comment: Running unity-reset solved the problem, however it crashed the UI and i am not really sure it did finish the job it was doing. The said software seems to be a bit immature.

Comment: it's not in the official repository. So yes, it's not something you should run regularly. Is the UI ok after re-login? Did Ubuntu-Tweak crash on you or was it just the unity-rest command?

Comment: unity-reset freezed and then then unity (or something related) crashed. 
i had to give a lightdm restart to recover.

the gui is ok now anyway.

Comment: Great to find this. Just tried it and it works great with my unity-2d setup (compiz crashes under xrdp).