# Why is my window resizing in the wrong direction?

Tags: window, resize

Somehow, I've screwed up window resizing in Ubuntu (14.04).

When I grab the top, right or left edge of a window with my mouse, everything works fine.

But when I grab the *bottom* of the window, then when I move my mouse *up*, the edge of the window goes *down*, and vice versa. It's very annoying and I have no idea how I got into that state.

How did I get into this state and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Ubuntu 14.04 with a somewhat customized Unity config, the problem was solved by running CCSM, finding the 'Window Management' section, disabling 'Resize Window', and then re-enabling 'Resize Window'.

CCSM can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

See [Unable to resize windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219411/unable-to-resize-windows) for screenshots of CCSM and the setting you need to find.

Answer (score 3):

I see you already got another answer but thought I should clarify my answer with the specific steps and also add the steps to RECREATE the condition since you and Neilen were not able to originally use my "fix".

You may do these steps to correct the reverse resizing motion:

1: Alt-F8

2: Press the Down Arrow once.

3: Press the Return Key.

Now you will find that you may click on the bottom edge of the window and resize it as normal.

You can also RE-CAUSE the problem to occur resulting in "reversed motion" of the bottom edge of the window during resizing by doing the following steps:

1. Alt-F8
2. Press the Up Arrow once
3. Press the Return Key.

I hope this helps clarify my work-around and makes the problem reproducible for others to fix this odd behavior!  I'm using Ubuntu 14.10.

Mike

Comment: Cool - I look forward to trying that. Once I do (since there is a - fairly remote - chance my problem has a different cause), I'll accept your answer. In the meantime, I will vote it up.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work for me in 14.04

Comment: I'm afraid this solution didn't work for me. I appreciate the answer, though.

Comment: Ah, that _does_ clarify it. Thank you very much!