# Let GNOME-Shell act like Unity by searching files or pressing ALT-key

Tags: gnome

I almost like the GNOME-Shell and would love it, if this is possible:

- searching windows, applications and **files** when pressing the <kbd>super</kbd> key
- searching the menu when pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key

This is possible in Unity but I don't want to fallback to that slow one. So how is this solveable in GNOME-Shell?

Comment: Okay. This is how I could get the alt-key behaviour back - in fact it doesn't show any results when I type something in. But now `gnome-shell` and `unity-2d-shell` is running and with that I could fully fallback to unity. Isn't there any extension that search files after pressing super and/or search the registered menu items after pressing alt?

Comment: Gnome team removed regent files recently. A workaround:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/128249/no-recent-files-in-gnome-shell-in-12-04

Answer (score 4):

Gnome team removed regent files recently. A workaround has been described here:

[No recent files in GNOME Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128249/no-recent-files-in-gnome-shell-in-12-04)

also

[Is there a shell-independent HUD-like menu search tool for Xfce/GNOME/Cinnamon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138657/is-there-a-shell-independent-hud-like-menu-search-tool-for-gnome)