# Unity-like dash in Ubuntu 18 when pressing Super

Tags: unity, gnome, shortcut-keys, unity-dash

I like Ubuntu 18.04/Gnome 3.28 so far, but there's one thing that bothers me: when pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> to search for something (e.g. a [recent file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128249/no-recent-files-in-gnome-shell)), there's a jarring transition from my current window to the desktop with the all the window previews exploded on it, then the windows disappearing as the search results are displayed:

[image: Super to search]

(See [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3udsa_2sPx8&t=822))

This is not just slow, but annoying. I don't need to see all my open windows when I just want to launch a new application of open a file.

What I want is just the search results overlaid onto the foreground window, the way Unity does it:

[image: Unity is fast]

(See [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pe3aUnL05kc&t=20), though this isn't a great demo as the guy didn't have any windows open at that point in the video; anyway, imagine there's a browser window open and you press <kbd>Super</kbd> - the window will stay open)

This is a lot faster than what Gnome does.

How can I get this behavior out of Gnome? Or do I need to install Unity?

Comment: You still can install Unity with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop` and drop GNOME sHell.