# How to find recent files in Ubuntu 20.04 activities overview?

Tags: files, gnome-shell, 20.04, search, activities-overview

Ubuntu unity made it easy to access recently used files by clicking on the dash button and type some characters of a recently used file. The activities overview in Ubuntu 20.04 works similar. But it does not show any results - instead a file search is triggered (taking a long time and usually without results).

Since Ubuntu can track my activities (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/privacy-history-recent-off.html.en) I suppose there a possibility to show these files in activities overview.

An older Ask Ubuntu thread posed a similar question, but is completely outdated:
[No recent files in GNOME Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128249/no-recent-files-in-gnome-shell)

I did not find any working gnome-extensions that can add this feature. My only solution so far has been to install an external launcher (Synapse).

Answer (score 1):

This extension might be what you're looking for:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/72/recent-items/